# How to split the dataset into train and test based on client number using "Federated learning"

Tags: python, tensorflow, federated-learning

I try to use `np.array.split` to split the dataset into 2 part, but it does not work well

Hope some one can give some advice on this issue

```
x` (images tensor) and `y` (labels) should have the same length. Found: x.shape = (14218, 32, 32, 3), y.shape = (2, 7109, 10)
```

Code part

```
y_train = utils.to_categorical(y_train_data, number_of_classes)  # one-hot encoding
y_test = utils.to_categorical(y_test_data, number_of_classes)   # one-hot encoding
# 查看一个类别样本
print('对应类别为7\n', y_train[1])

'''clients_num = 2
X_train = np.array_split(X_train, clients_num)
y_train = np.array_split(y_train, clients_num)
print(np.shape(y_train))'''

input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

rgb_batch = np.repeat(X_train_data[..., np.newaxis], 3, -1)
rgb_batch1 = np.repeat(X_test_data[..., np.newaxis], 3, -1)

X_train = tf.image.resize(rgb_batch, (32, 32))
X_test = tf.image.resize(rgb_batch1, (32, 32))

tf.dtypes.cast(X_train, tf.float32)
tf.dtypes.cast(X_test, tf.float32)

X_train /= 255.0
X_test /= 255.0
```

Comment: Is the dataset you want to split a tensorflow dataset or numpy arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have `X_train` and `Y_train` that are numpy arrays representing your dataset. If you want to divide it in random parts, you could for instance shuffle the datasets and then take the first shuffled part for the 1st client and the second for the second client:

```
rand_indexes= np.arange(len(X_train))
np.random.shuffle(rand_indexes)
X_rand  = X_train[rand_indexes]
Y_rand  = Y_train[rand_indexes]
X_1_train = X_rand[0:num_samples_1]
Y_1_train = Y_rand[0:num_samples_1]
X_2_train = X_rand[num_samples_1:]
Y_2_train = Y_rand[num_samples_1:]
```

Comment: Is the dataset you want to split a tensorflow dataset or numpy arrays? - “After changing the dimension, it is a numpy array”

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I will try it.

Comment: It successfully split it into 2 parts, but when I put it into `model.fit`, it sends me "ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible" , I really don't know where the 10 come from? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: That depends on your model output layer. Make sure that the number of classes in your dataset is equal to the number of output classes of your model. It seems like they are diffferent (10 and 1) in your case

Comment: I check it, the `y_test` is (3550, 10), and the num_classes in the model is also 10, the error is still happen

Comment: Sorry to bother you, should I split the `X_test` into 2 part also, or stay the same compared with before